# Got a problem while publishing in iis, session variables are disappearing(c#)

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

The deal is that i'm working a page that is using session variables for the Login, while working on visual Studio with iisExpress i got no problem, but right now while publishing the page the session variables are disappearing when i change to another page.

i have tried looking in the web.config file but seems ok for me

This is the web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\PQR.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
  <sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

[This is how i have the session state in my IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0eaY.png)

In permissions over the project folder i have IUSR, IIS_IUSRS, the data pool and the server user i guess thats all i need

the login code is this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login(ConexionDB con, IFormCollection collection)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string pass = Convert.ToString(collection["pass"]);
                string user = Convert.ToString(collection["user"]);
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("user", user);
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("pass", pass);

                TipoUsuariosModel tipo = new TipoUsuariosModel();


                if (con.Conexion(user, pass))
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("tipo", tipo.tipo(user, pass));
                    if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("tipo") == "Estandar")
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Report", "Reporte");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Usuario o Contraseña invalido, porfavor revisar";
                }
            }
            return View(con);
        }
```

if Login got right it redirects the user to this other controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(DashboardQuejasModel dashboard, ConexionDB conexion)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("user")))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Conexion");
            }
            if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("tipo") != "TI" && HttpContext.Session.GetString("tipo") != "Calidad")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Report", "Reporte");
            }
            dashboard.quejas_count = _context.Quejas.Count();
            int sin = 0;
            int at = 0;
            int mon = 0;
            List<string> Responsable = new List<string>();
            foreach (var row in _context.Quejas.ToList())
            {
                if (row.Estado.Contains("S")|| row.Estado.Contains("P"))
                {
                    sin++;
                }
                else if(row.Estado.Contains("A"))
                {
                    at++;
                }

                if (row.Recibido.Month.Equals(DateTime.Today.Month))
                {
                    mon++;
                }
            }
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conexion.chain(HttpContext.Session.GetString("user"), HttpContext.Session.GetString("pass"))))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    try
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[PQR].[V_RESPONSABLE]", conn))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    Responsable.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                                }
                                conn.Close();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine("Error {2}: " + ex);
                                throw;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error {1}: " + ex);
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error {0}: " + ex);
                throw;
            }

            ViewBag.lista = _context.Quejas.ToList();
            ViewBag.Responsable = Responsable;

            dashboard.quejas_sin_count = sin;
            dashboard.quejas_at_count = at;
            dashboard.quejas_mon_count = mon;


            return View(dashboard);
        }
```

At this point the session var is coming null so it disappear and when the login ask for it cause it's null it redirects again to the login page.

---------Edit-----------

This is my startup.cs file

````
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.Configure<IISOptions>(options => {
                options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<EMSContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PQRDatabase")));
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env);


            //enable session before MVC
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Conexion}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Could you please post the details codes about the ConfigureServices method in the startup.cs file? I need to know the session related config for your asp.net core application.

Comment: sure, already edited my post with my startup cs file